# How to apply Wilcoxon test to each row of a Matrix by for loop under R

Tags: r, matrix, row, multiple-columns

I am new to R, I have a quick question, how to apply Wilcoxon test to every row of a matrix under R?
for example, as the simplest matrix. I am trying to apply the Wilcoxon test to every row by for loop, two groups of columns, columns 1 to 5 as a group, and 6 to 10 as another group. And save the P-values as a column to a file. I wrote two for loops but failed. I put mine for loops and error messages in the last. Thank you so much.

```
mymatrix
       [,1][,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]  [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100



     for (i in nrow(mymatrix)){
           vector1 <- c(mymatrix[i,1:5]) 
            vector2 <- c(mymatrix[i,6:10])
             wilcox.test(vector1,vector2, paired = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided")
         }

    #Warning message:
    In wilcox.test.default(vector1, vector2, paired = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided") :
    cannot compute exact p-value with ties

    # I also tried this, it doesn't work either.

 for (i in nrow(mymatrix)){
  wilcox.test(as.numeric(mymatrix[i,1:5],as.numeric(mymatrix[i,6:10]), paired = TRUE)
 }
```

Comment: (1) *"apply ... to each row"* is `apply(mymatrix, 1, function(m) wilcox.test(m[1:5], m[6:10], ...)$p.value)`. (2) You execute the test but discard its output into the ether ... are you hoping that it will modify your data in-place without you telling it to do that? How would it know that you want to add `$p.value` and not `$statistic` or any of the other returned values? (3) The warning about *"cannot compute exact p-value with ties"* is something you really need to deal with, either by fixing ties before the test or something else.

Comment: Thank you so much. but How to write a for loop for that? Because I need to practice it.  I tried Pvalue <- mymatrix$p.value, and mymatrix$pvalue <- Pvalue, but it won't work. I don't understand the ties mean.

Comment: `$` is not appropriate for matrices. Perhaps you mean for `mymatrix` to be converted to a `data.frame` at some point? (I tend to not like combining arbitrary differently-purposed numbers to a matrix, with the assumption that all numbers in a matrix have the same "unit" or "meaning"; once you start adding another "meaning" as a column, the structure is really better suited as a `data.frame` (or the new column should be kept separate). That might be data-snobbery, but I believe most matrix-centric tools assume that all object in it are created equally ... and p-values look nothing like the above

Comment: As to the "ties" thing, I suggest you read [`?wilcox.test`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html) and search for "ties", it is clear in its documentation.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to R, I don't know much about it, but will go to learn the points you mentioned.

Comment: When I get an error or warning that I don't understand, my first place to search is the function's help page, and I search for a key word in the error. After that, I search (both on SO and just Google) for the literal error (in double quotes, removing variables names), and that often finds something. An infrequent tactic (when I don't know the exact source of the error)  is to look for the error message in https://GitHub.com/wch/r-source, though that's uncommon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looking for something like this:

```
# initialize a list to store the p_values
p_values <- vector("list", nrow(mymatrix))

for(i in seq_along(1: nrow(mymatrix))){
  p_values[i] = wilcox.test(mymatrix[i,1:5],mymatrix[i,6:10], paired = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided", exact = FALSE)$p.value

}
# make it a data.frame
p_values = data.frame(p_values = sapply(p_values, c))
#Output
p_values

#     p_values
# 1  0.03688843
# 2  0.03688843
# 3  0.03688843
# 4  0.03688843
# 5  0.03688843
# 6  0.03688843
# 7  0.03688843
# 8  0.03688843
# 9  0.03688843
# 10 0.03688843
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It helps a lot. Thank you so much. Then I am gonna learn some commands such as vector and data.frame.

Comment: Any idea if I want to save v.value (or other useful information) as well? what's the best way to do it?

Comment: replace `p.value` with `statistic` for the value of the test statistic. You might want to check the `Value` section of the `?wilcox.test` for rest.